# changing json entity in elasticsearch, is it allowed?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to change already created and used json entity in elasticsearch?
I want to add new field and delete one.

Would elasticsearch still work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. You can modify the existing data which includes insert, delete and update fields.

Note that you can not change the mapping (type) of fields. For example if something is float type, you can not convet that to geopoint etc.